# Unresponsive OnMouseOver event in a dynamically-generated nested DIV

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am using JavaScript to generate a map for a game, and each tile is a separate div.  In order to be able to position the map on my site, I am throwing them all in another div.

So for example:

```
<div id="mapBox">  
    <div id="tile" ... ></div>  
    <div id="tile" ... ></div>  
</div>
```

The `#tile` divs are generated from data in an XML file, so they're dynamically generated.  On each `#tile`, I have an `onmouseevent` that triggers a function (`alert(1)` for now just to get it to work) but it never seems to be triggered.

If I put an `onmouseevent` on `#mapBox` it triggers it, but I can't get it to work for the `#tile` divs.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you're selecting the `#tile` divs, but it is not valid to have multiple elements with the same ID.

Selection using duplicate IDs will often give you only the first match (or some other unpredictable behavior).

When a duplicate identifier is needed, you should use a class instead of an ID.

```
<div id="mapBox">
    <div class="tile" ... ></div>
    <div class="tile" ... ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Class is already used for something else, but thanks.  This still doesn't solve the issue however. :/

Comment: @TheJF - You can have more than one class per element. Just use a single white space to separate them. `<div class="someClass tile" ... ></div>` How are you selecting the elements in order to assign the handler?

Comment: Oh, I knew about the id but tested it out anyhow.  But I didn't know you could assign more than one class to an element, thanks!

Comment: The handler is assigned inline, as in <div class="grass tile" ... onmouseover="alert(1);"></div>

Comment: @TheJF - If the handler is assigned inline, not sure why it wouldn't fire. As @Gaby indicated, you can use event delegation for this. No need to use jQuery for it. Give me a minute and I'll put together a couple of examples.

Comment: @TheJF - [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/jVRGe/) using your code. As you can see, it should work. [This example uses delegation](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/jVRGe/1/) you can see that there's only one handler on the parent `<div>`. It fires when any of its children gets a `mouseover`. The function checks to see if the child has the class `tile`, then alerts that element's `id` attribute.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, although I must have something else that's wrong with my code because it's still not working.  I'll post a few relevant lines from my code, maybe that will make things clearer.

Comment: (Agh, keep hitting enter, not used to Stack Overflow yet.)  `txt = txt + '<div class="' + tileType + ' tile" style="width: '+ tileWidth +'; height: '+ tileHeightTotal  + '; position: absolute; top:' + tileTop + 'px; left:' + tileRight + 'px;z-index: '+ pointerY + ';" onmouseover="alert(1);"></div>';` That's in a loop to generate all the tiles from the XML data, then a few lines down, `document.getElementById("mapBox").innerHTML=txt;`

Comment: Actually, the delegate(event) function works after all, I just need to modify my approach at getting the information that I need from it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First problem, as mentioned, is that you use the same id for many elements, so the event only fires on the first one.

Secondly you should use the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method on the `#mapBox` after giving a class on the tiles like this

```
$('#mapBox').delegate('.tile', 'mouseover', function(e){
    //do whatever here
})
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/nXa27/1/

---

**Update**

Sorry, didn't see you were not talking about jquery..

Here is an example with pure javascript http://www.jsfiddle.net/AvJf7/

Still you will need to add a `tile` class to your tiles for easy and valid selecting.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, but this is using jQuery right?  I haven't taken the time to learn that yet.  Is there any solution that doesn't use jQuery, or should I just stop everything and go learn it before continuing my project?

Comment: @theJF, oups. Thought you were asking about jquery. Added an pure JS example. jQuery is pretty handy if you need it.. Have a read and see if it fits your needs ;)

Comment: Ahh, thank you for you help!  patrick dw's answer did the trick, although I need to use it a bit differently than I was hoping, but I really appreciate the answers. :)